# Broken Image placeholder for uploading images

Tags: php, html

Good day everyone, so I have a code here for my site for uploading images to customer profile photos, but if they haven't uploaded yet it shows a broken image, how do I put a placeholder instead of a broken image.

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href=
                ""><img class="img-hover" src="<?php echo web_root. "customer/".$res->CUSPHOTO; ?>"
                style="width:100%; height:100%;text-align:center" title=
                "profile image"></a>
            </div>
```

This is my code for uploading the image

```
function doupdateimage(){

            $errofile = $_FILES['photo']['error'];
            $type = $_FILES['photo']['type'];
            $temp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
            $myfile =$_FILES['photo']['name'];
            $location="customer_image/".$myfile;


        if ( $errofile > 0) {
                message("No Image Selected!", "error");
                redirect(web_root. "index.php?q=profile");
        }else{

                @$file=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
                @$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']));
                @$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['photo']['name']);
                @$image_size= getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']);

            if ($image_size==FALSE ) {
                message(web_root. "Uploaded file is not an image!", "error");
                redirect(web_root. "index.php?q=profile");
            }else{
                    //uploading the file
                    move_uploaded_file($temp,"customer_image/" . $myfile);


                        $customer = New Customer();
                        $customer->CUSPHOTO         = $location;
                        $customer->update($_SESSION['CUSID']);

                        redirect(web_root. "index.php?q=profile");
```

Comment: What value does `$res->CUSPHOTO` have when the customer hasn't uploaded a photo?

Comment: It basically has no value so it's a broken image link by default not until they update their image through their profile

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "basically has no value" means [NULL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) you could check for that value:

```
<?php
    if (is_null($res->CUSPHOTO)) {
      $url = web_root. "customer/anonymous.jpg";
    }
    else {
      $url = web_root. "customer/".$res->CUSPHOTO;
    }
?>
<div class="panel-body">
    <a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="">
         <img class="img-hover" 
              src=<?php echo '"'.$url.'"' ?>
              style="width:100%; height:100%;text-align:center"
              title="profile image">
    </a>
</div>
```

Here `anonymous.jpg` is the image to be displayed when no photo has been uploaded.

*Opinion:* Personally I don't like mixing the PHP tags into HTML like that. You never know exactly what will happen. I always write either HTML or PHP, not mixed, but I know it can be done. That's the reason I do the strange thing with the quotes around `$url`, I really don't like a PHP tag inside a HTML string.

Comment: Thanks, however that didn't do the trick, sorry I'm fairly new to php cuz I'm still a student.

Comment: @VincentFrancisco The most likely reason it didn't work is because `$res->CUSPHOTO` probably isn't NULL when no photo has been uploaded. You should check that assumption.

Comment: Yeah it's probably not null because when a user registers the value of CUSPHOTO on my database is just blank.

Comment: although I was able to make a work-around using onerror="this.src='customer/anonymous.jpg'", nonetheless thank you for trying, cheers!

Comment: You could replace `is_null()` by `empty()` in that case. That will also work for empty strings, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: @VincentFrancisco I would not use `onerror`. Support for it is not fantastic, see: https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_img_onerror It also says there _"This feature is deprecated/obsolete and should not be used."_